# How can I find out the missing Markov transition probabilities given an incomplete transition graph?

Tags: probability, statistics, markov-chains, markov-process

I'm given a transition graph as shown below. I need to fill in the two missing probabilities. Is there a general method for doing this?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, we have to use the fact that the total probability add up to $1$ for a variable.

So, from $B$ to $A$ the probability is $1-0.6=0.4$

Probability of staying at $A$ is $1-0.3 =0.7$